# how to see the changes made in a big perl script having the copy of original that is to compare both in a splitted gvim editor simultaneously

Tags: perl, gvim

In a particular perl script and I have a copy of the same  but with the changes made in it i want to see both the scripts in such a way that changes made in the copy to be highlighted in a split gvim editor,so that I can compare both simultaneously.What should i do for that?. I know to split gvim but I don.t know how to compare

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the tool you may be looking for is `vimdiff`

```
vimdiff file.copy file.original
```

Comment: or `gvimdiff` if OP prefers gvim over vim